# Compare all pairs of values in a dictionary

Tags: python

Can someone tell me how can i compare all values to each other on the same dictionary please?

I have a dictionary named `dic_trans`, it contains all the translated sequences witch were translated into amino acid sequences with a specific function.

The keys are the dna sequences and the values are the amino acid sequences:

```
dic_trans[sequence] = trans
```

I want to compare each value (aa sequence) to all other values (aa sequences) to find the similar ones (the duplicates) in order to delete the corresponding dna sequences =====> goal: Clean the dna sequences

Comment: What does "compare" mean? What if all the values are equal? what if all except for 1 value are equal? Also, what are the types of the values? are they all hashable?

Comment: I imagine you want to use [**`itertools.combinations`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) e.g: `itertools.combinations(sequence_translations.values(). 2)`

Comment: Happy to edit once I understand the problem. Could you please provide an example with a clear input and what you want to get returned. Thx

Comment: can you tell me if it's clear now please?? thank you :)

Comment: Do you want to remove similar translations or exact translations? i.e. if a translation matches why doesn't the sequence also match (duplicate key)?

Comment: because we can have different dna sequences that could be translated into the same amino acid, it's called genetic polymorphism in biology.

Comment: ps: excuse the mistakes, i'm not really good in english :/

Comment: @Amel.mek so how do you know which sequence you'd rather keep, or doesn't it matter?

Comment: it doesn't matter!! if i find for exemple 3 same amino acids, i have to keep only of them randomly !

Comment: Why not create a second dictionary where the key was the DNA sequence and the value was the aa sequence and use a hashtable to find the dups?

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about two things.

Iterating over a sequence whilst modifying it can lead to problems. So you need to either copy the contents of the dictionary first and then modify the dictionary, or build a list of keys to remove, and afterwards remove them.

I don't know how large your dictionary is. If it isn't too large you could build a list of the keys you want to remove, and then remove them one by one:

```
for sequence in sequences_to_remove:
    del sequence_trans[sequence]
```

Alternatively, you could create a brand new dictionary from the old one but filter out the sequences you don't want:

```
unique_sequence_trans = {sequence: trans
                         for sequence, trans in sequence_trans.items()
                         if sequence not in sequences_to_remove}
```

Secondly, the main part of the question is how to find the duplicates. It's not so much that you want to compare every `trans` with every other `trans`, rather you want to keep sequences which have a unique `trans`:

```
seen_trans = set()
sequences_to_remove = set()
for sequence, trans in sequence_trans.items():
    if trans in seen_trans:
        sequences_to_remove.add(sequence)
    else:
        seen_trans.add(trans)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
So, yes my files can be huge, they can contain a million of sequences!
I tried to use your script but the add() fonction doesn't work:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: @Amel.mek Sorry, my mistake, it should have been a `set` not a `dict`. Fixed.